# Calling super method of inherited subclass' superclass

Tags: swift, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm reading Swift and got a question.
Am I allowed to call base class' method from "double inherited" class? (Wording may be isn't that good)
The code is below.

I have tried super.super.makeNoise() in FastTrain class, but that's wrong

```
class Vehicle {
    var currentSpeed = 0.0
    var description: String {
        return "traveling at \(currentSpeed) miles per hour"
    }
    func makeNoise() {
        print("No noise")
    }
}

class Train: Vehicle {
    override func makeNoise() {
        print("Choo Choo")
    }
}

class FastTrain: Train {
    override func makeNoise() {
        super.makeNoise()
        print("Silent noise")
    }
}
```

I want to call Vehicle's makeNoise() method from FastTrain class

Comment: Shouldn't you call `super.makeNoise()` in `Train` class same as you did in `FastTrain`?

Comment: I was thinking about it. But what if I don't need to call super method in Train and only need to call in FastTrain?

Comment: You won't be able to do that.